# Random lagging in Skate 2

Tags: ps3, skate-2

Just bought (EA) Skate 2 for PS3 (500gb) a couple of weeks back and it started off having a few minor lagging problems. However, it's become really bad and I'm wondering if this is normal for Skate 2, and is there a fix?

Comment: Where does it lag specifically?

Comment: it seems to be at random really...